# Position.longitude or latitude returns null and most of the time returns nothing

Tags: flutter

Here is the code , as I mentioned most of the time it returns nothing, but once it has returned null, the permission is enabled and nothing wrong with it.

```
    class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
      double latitude;
      double longitude ;
      @override
      void initState() {
      
        getLocation();
      }
    
    
      void getLocation() async{
    
    
        Location location = new Location();
        await location.getCurrentLocation();
        latitude = (location.latitude);
        longitude= (location.longitude);
        getData();
    
      }
    
      void getData() async{
        http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude &appid= $apiKey'));
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          String data = response.body ;
          var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
         // var longitude = decodedData["coord"]["lon"];
          var weatherDescription = decodedData["weather"][0]["description"];
          int id = decodedData["weather"][0]["id"];
          double temp = decodedData["main"]["temp"];
          String city = decodedData["name"];
    
          print("hi");
          print(id);
          print(temp);
          print(city);
          print(latitude);
          print(longitude);
    
    
        }
        else {
          print(response.statusCode);
        }
    
      }
```

and here is the location class , the permission is enabled and nothing wrong with it.
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Location{
  double latitude ;
  double longitude ;


  Future <void> getCurrentLocation() async{
    // bool servicestatus = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    //
    // servicestatus ? print("GPS service is enabled"): print("GPS service is disabled.");

    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);

      latitude = position.latitude;
      longitude = position.longitude;
    }
    catch (exception){
      print(exception);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try printing `position` inside the  `getCurrentLocation` method,

Comment: returns nothing

Comment: it is possible to get null value, try debugging the app or just print `location` to check if it contains value or not like under `    await location.getCurrentLocation();
`